# Java recursion and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, recursion

I have two classes like below:

```
public class Animal {
    public void askForLocation() {
        System.out.println("In animal");
        System.out.println("Street?");

        Scanner inFromConsole = new Scanner(System.in);
        String street = inFromConsole.nextLine();
        if (street.equals(""))
            this.askForLocation();
        else
            System.out.println("Street: " + street);
        }
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void askForLocation() {
        Scanner inFromConsole = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("In dog");
        String city;
        super.askForLocation(); 

        System.out.println("Back in dog");    
        System.out.println("City?");

        city = inFromConsole.nextLine();

        System.out.println("city: " + city);
    }
}
```

Then I run the following code:

```
public class TestAnimals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("----");
        Dog doggy = new Dog();
        doggy.askForLocation();
    }
}
```

When I give an empty string as an argument for street the first time I get the following output:

```
1  In dog
2  In animal
3  Street?
4 
5  In dog
6  In animal
7  Street?
8  Main Street
9  Street: Main Street
10 Back in dog
11 City?
12 NY
13 city: NY
14 Back in dog
15 City?
16 NY
17 city: NY
```

It's two things that I don't understand:

1. In line 5 of the output the call to `askForLocation` is a call to `askForLocation` in the class `Dog` and not in the class `Animal`.
   Why is this? I want it to call `askForLocation` in the class `Animal`, so I was expecting not to see line 5 at all.
2. Line 14-17 in the output. I can't understand why the code executes tt all. I was expecting it to end at line 13.

Would be really nice if someone could explain this.
I can get around the problem by renaming the method `askForLocation()` in the class dog to for example `askForLocation2()`, but I want to know how it works.

Comment: I want the want the statements following the super.askForLocation() call to be executed, but I want the method in Animal to be recursive and not call the method in the dog class.

Comment: Line 10-13 are still statements following the super.askForLocation(). I just don't see why it's executed 2 times (lines 10-13) then (lines 14-17).

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question 1 : "this" refers to the current object being executed. In your case current object being executed is "Dog". Since Java uses dynamic binding for resolving overriding methods, so this.askForLocation(), will invoke the method of Dog class.

Answer to question 2 : you can understand this by creating a stack trace.

main(1) ->

Dog,askForLocation(2)->

Animal,askForLocation(3) ->

Dog,askForLocation(4)->

Animal,askForLocation(5)

After completing 5th one, control will go back to 4 one, will complete the remaining statements(statements after super.askForLocation(); ), call to 3rd one is already completed, then control will go back to 2 one executing the remaining statements(statements after super.askForLocation(); ), finally control will come back to main() where program will finish execution.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call in `Animal#askForLocation` calls `askForLocation` on `this`. It doesn't call `Animal#askForLocation`. It calls `this.askForLocation`, whatever that is. If `this` is a `Dog`, it calls `Dog#askForLocation`, because that's what would happen in any other code, whether its in another method in `Animal`, or outside these classes entirely. Imagine, e.g. doing `Animal foo; if (bar) foo = this else foo = ...; foo.askForLocation();`. You need to be specific that you want to call the code written in the `Animal` class. The easiest way is:

```
public class Animal {
     private void askForLocationLoop() {
       // ...
     }
     public void askForLocation() {
       askForLocationLoop();
     }
}
public class Dog extends Anumal {
     @Override
     public void askForLocation() {
       // ...
     }
}
```

`private` methods entirely bypass virtual dispatch; any recursive call in `askForLocationLoop` will always go back to it, even if a subclass declares another method with the same name, because it's a `private` method.

For your output, I'll show you the call stack for each line:

- 1: `Dog#askForLocation`
- 2-4: `Dog#askForLocation` > `Animal#askForLocation`
- 5: `Dog#askForLocation` > `Animal#askForLocation` > `Dog#askForLocation`
- 6-9: `Dog#askForLocation` > `Animal#askForLocation` > `Dog#askForLocation` > `Animal#askForLocation`
- 10-13: `Dog#askForLocation` > `Animal#askForLocation` > `Dog#askForLocation`
- 14-17: `Dog#askForLocation`.

There are two `Dog#askForLocation`s in the stack. When the second one returns, the `Animal#askForLocation` above it also returns, so between 13 and 14 we go up two methods.

---

Now, for "fun"

```
// given f : (A -> B) -> (A -> B), calculate g : A -> B
// such that f(g) = g, making g the fixed point of f,
// and then call g on an A
static <A, B> B fix(Function<Function<A, B>, Function<A, B>> f, A a) {
  return f.apply(a2 -> fix(f, a2)).apply(a);
}
public class Animal
    public void askForLocation() {
        Function<Function<Void, Void>, Function<Void, Void>> step = continu -> ign -> {
            System.out.println("In animal");
            System.out.println("Street?");
            String street = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            if(street.equals(""))
                return continu.apply(null);
            else
                System.out.println("Street: " + street);
            return null;
        };
        fix(step, null);
        // we write step in terms of open recursion; it gets an argument
        // continu that it can call to "recurse" and fix feeds step to itself.
        // that is; fix lets you write recursion indirectly.
    }        
}
```

Now you don't have to explicitly write a `private` method (but the compiler will end up doing so anyway by lifting the lambda).

---

Or you may just use a `do`-`while` loop:

```
public class Animal
    public void askForLocation() {
        String street;
        do {
            System.out.println("In animal");
            System.out.println("Street?");
            street = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        } while(street.equals(""));
        System.out.println("Street: " + street);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing with the `askForLocation` method is called 'dynamic binding'. When you call a (non-private) instance method, then Java resolves the class of the instance at runtime, in this case `Dog`, and will always look for this method in that class first. Only if it doesn't find it there, it "goes up the inheritence ladder" (from point of view of your code), in this case to class `Animal`. But as you have overriden the method in class Dog, it will always execute the overriden version of the method from the Dog class, no matter from what class you call it. Note that `this` in class Animal refers to the instance in context, which is still a Dog.

I guess you could just put your code in the Animal class in a loop instead of doing recursive calls to the method. But there may be a better way to do it, my answer is mainly about explaining to you why your program behaves as it does.

Answer (score 0):

On start of execution from here `doggy.askForLocation();` you got `Dog` class function callled-

```
    public void askForLocation() {
    Scanner inFromConsole = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("In dog");
    String city;
    super.askForLocation(); 

    System.out.println("Back in dog");    
    System.out.println("City?");

    city = inFromConsole.nextLine();

    System.out.println("city: " + city);
}
```

Now when it came to `super.askForLocation()` it went to Animal class and from there you entered nothing so it called `this.askForLocatioon()`.
 Now `this` refers to the current object which is `doggy` of `Dog` class so again `Dog's` class function -`askForLocation()` called on line 5 .
 Now in animal class you enter the `street` and control  passes back to the `Dog` class function and you run the rest of the code. 

After this, the control passes to the first instance of `askForLocation()` function in the stack that could not complete because u called `this.askForLocation()`.

And thats why you get the code repeated 14-17.

The subsequent function calls get stacked up in the stack.

A simple workaround could be like this:

```
public class Animal {
public void askForLocation() {
    System.out.println("In animal");
    System.out.println("Street?");

    Scanner inFromConsole = new Scanner(System.in);
    String street = inFromConsole.nextLine();
    while (street.equals("")) {
      System.out.println("Street?");
      street = inFromConsole.nextLine();
    }

    else
        System.out.println("Street: " + street);
    }
   }
 }
```

There could be better workarounds too.